# Problema com o uso de herança no Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Olá, boa noite galera!

Estou com um problema referente ao relacionamento e mapeamento entre as minhas classes no Java e as tabelas no banco de dados postgresql. Atualmente o meu projeto está com duas classes, uma chamada Pessoa e outra Aluno. Segue abaixo o código de cada uma delas:

**Pessoa.java**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
      
   public class Pessoa {

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Long id;

     private String nome;

     private int idade;

     private long cpf;

     private long telefone;

     @Column(name = "datanascimento")
     private String dataNascimento;

     private String email;
   }
```

**Aluno.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "alunos")
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
public class Aluno extends Pessoa {

   private int matricula;

   private String objetivo;

   @Column(name = "dataadmissao")
   private String dataAdmissao;

   @Column(name = "tipoplano")
   private String tipoPlano;

   @Column(name = "resultadoavaliacaomedica")
   private boolean resultadoAvaliacaoMedica;

   @Column(name = "mensalidadeemdia")
   private boolean mensalidadeEmDia;
}
```

Já tenho um database criado no postgres e uma tabela **alunos** com todos os atributos de ambas as classes. Quando eu não uso a anotação @Inheritance e realizo o teste no Postman ele consegue acessar a rota e receber os dados do banco via GET normalmente, só que os atributos pertencentes a classe Pessoa, que é a super classe, ficam com valores *null*.

Já tentei usar @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS), @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE) mas sempre retornam o seguinte erro:

**ERROR 11720 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Cannot use identity column key generation with  mapping for: com.api.academia.entity.Pessoa**

**Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-10-04T23:44:43.655-03:00 ERROR 11720 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed**

Por favor! Alguém sabe por que isso está acontecendo?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi, você não vai ter uma tabela "pessoas" no seu banco

nesse caso, você deve substituir a anotação @Entity por @MappedSuperclass em Pessoa. Isso vai informar ao Hibernate que ele não deve esperar existir uma tabela dessa classe no banco.